# Outlets no Xcode 6 (Aplicativo Universal)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, iphone

Estou com um problema/dúvidas. Até hoje devido algumas necessidades desenvolvi apenas para iPhone ou iPad separadamente, porém hoje estou iniciando no desenvolvimento de aplicativo universal, iPhone e iPad.

Estou utilizando o Xcode 6 e desenvolvendo diretamente para iOS 8. Consegui adaptar as telas para ambos os dispositivos, ficou legalzão exceto pelo fato de que: quando construi as telas utilizando o *storyboard*, adicionei uma `UITabBar` e referenciei a mesma como `Outlet` na minha controladora. Quando adaptei para a tela do iPad, tive de adicionar outra `UITabBar` (na verdade tive de adicionar todos os componentes, pois a mesma estava vazia). Ao tentar referenciar como `Outlet` na classe, eu não consegui, pois ela "sobrescreve", perdendo meu outlet da tela do iPhone e vice versa.

As minhas dúvida é a seguinte:

- Qual a melhor forma de se fazer isso?
- Toda vez que eu criar uma tela para o iPhone e adaptar a tela para o iPad, terei de adicionar todos os componentes novamente?
- Em caso de sobrescrever, qual a alternativa correta para fazer isso?
- Eu precisarei ter duas controladoras? Uma para iPad e outra para iPhone?

**IMPORTANTE:** Para saber como eu crio o layout e códigos: não escrevi nenhum código, ainda estou na fase da criação das telas e crio o layout da mesma maneira que neste vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5wD8dvSDbM

Comment: Se você desenhou seu layout para iPhone e iPad, realmente não é possível referenciar ao mesmo `IBOutlet`, a menos que você desenhe um mesmo layout com **Any|Any** e utilizando as **constraints** corretamente. A `UITabBar` por exemplo, é uma das coisas que não consigo imaginar porque não conseguiu fazer de forma universal sem precisar de 2 `IBOutlet`.

Comment: @PauloRodrigues o problema realmente era no Any|Any. Depois de ver seu comentário observei que o problema estava onde inseri os componentes na tela de iPhone e não na tela Any|Any, não podendo assim duplicar para o iPad. Poderia por favor, colocar como resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De fato não é possível fazer referência para um mesmo `IBOutlet` se você possui layouts diferentes para iPhone e iPad, por exemplo.

Você desenhando um único layout no modo **wAny|hAny**, note que no preview e mesmo no vídeo que você indicou, é possível utilizar o mesmo componente e a chave para isso é a utilização das **constaints** de forma correta.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como no seu caso, a `UITabBar` você consegue o mesmo resultado de forma universal e com o mesmo `IBOutlet` aplicando as **constraints** de largura, alinhamento central, fixar junto ao rodapé e etc.